# Automatically refresh onOpen() after changing language. Complicated by html-sidebar and Library

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries

My (Google Apps Script) addon-meny builds its menu in two parts: one part (addSharedMenu) is in a shared library, and one part is environment-specific functions; docs, sheets, slide ..

Language is a user property and it's updated via the shared menu-function. It opens a sidebar that updates the language-property. It works.

After the language is updated, I want to refresh the menu, with the new language. I've unable to get my library-functions to access/refresh onOpen. The best I've been able to do, is adding an addition meny-alternative for refreshing.

```
// opAddonShared is name of Library
function onOpen(e) {  // Runs in a Spreadsheet (docs, slide .. have different unique functions)
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createAddonMenu();
  let lang = opAddonShared.getLanguage()

  menu.addItem(menuPasswordColumn_(lang),  'makePasswordColumn')
  menu.addItem(menuClearEmptyCells_(lang),  'removeEmpty')
  opAddonShared.addSharedMenu(ui, menu).addToUi() 
}

function addSharedMenu (ui, menu) {  // Runs in Library: opAddonShared
  let lang = getLanguage()
  menu.addSeparator();
  menu.addItem(menuReload_(lang), 'onOpen');
  menu.addItem(menuLanguage_(lang), 'opAddonShared.languageDialog');
  return menu
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate function that executes the same statements as the onOpen function?

Comment: I don't understand which line of code you want to run when? Can you clarify it please?

Comment: onOpen() runs automatically and lists menu (in English). Users may change language (to Swedish), via opAddonShared.languageDialog. I want the function to refresh onOpen to update the language in the menu.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the properties service to add the desired language for the user. And then Have onOpen read from PropertiesService

Comment: That's being done. But when the languate is updated, the onOpen isn't automatically refreshed. It needs to rerun. But I can't access the Spreadsheet-function (onOpen) from the library-function (languageDialog).

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to tell the user with an alert to refresh the browser tab after selecting the custom menu. Because access to cross-origin frames are blocked.